# Spring SAML Single Logout - NameID format mismatch

Tags: spring, spring-saml

This is related to [Spring Security SAML One Login Global Single Logout LogoutRequest Parsing Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33931488/spring-security-saml-one-login-global-single-logout-logoutrequest-parsing-issue)

The problem here is that the NameID format is not matching, as per:

```
private boolean equalsNameID(NameID a, NameID b) {
    boolean equals = !differ(a.getSPProvidedID(), b.getSPProvidedID());
    equals = equals && !differ(a.getValue(), b.getValue());
    equals = equals && !differ(a.getFormat(), b.getFormat());
    equals = equals && !differ(a.getNameQualifier(), b.getNameQualifier());
    equals = equals && !differ(a.getSPNameQualifier(), b.getSPNameQualifier());
    equals = equals && !differ(a.getSPProvidedID(), b.getSPProvidedID());
    return equals;
}
```

It's failing ONLY on:

```
equals = equals && !differ(a.getFormat(), b.getFormat());
```

Upon debugging, I found out the following values:

```
a.getFormat() = urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified (from Spring SAML)
b.getFormat() = null (from OneLogin acting as the IdP)
```

Is it possible to turn off the format check in Spring SAML via extended metadata properties (or in some other way)?

Comment: I'll look into this

Comment: @VladimírSchäfer: Did you get a chance to look into this? Thanks.